# ¿Cuál es la razón por la que se corrije "yo y tú" a "tú y yo"?

Tags: pronombres, cortesía

Desde niño he sabido que "el burro por delante", y siempre se debe poner uno mismo al final de una lista de pronombres ("Juan, Paco y yo", en lugar de "yo, Juan y Paco"), sin embargo, ¿cuál es la razón detrás de esto?

He intentado buscar un poco de información pero nada al respecto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es solo por educación, realmente no hay razones gramaticales para el orden y el propio [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yo) así lo dice en su entrada sobre *yo*:

> Por razones de cortesía, es costumbre colocarlo en último lugar cuando forma parte de una enumeración: «Andrés, Quique y yo caminábamos entre las tumbas» (GaRamis Días [P. Rico 1986]); no hay, sin embargo, justificación lingüística para censurar su anteposición: «Te querrán tanto como yo y Leonardo D’Amaro te hemos querido» (Alegre Locus [Esp. 1989]).

Comment: Y no pasa sólo en castellano: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-I-and-you-or-you-and-I

Comment: Yo y el resto de usuarios de [spanish.se] agradecemos tu respuesta, blonfu :D

Comment: De todas formas, esto es sólo una convención: en italiano es muy frecuente decir "io e ...".