# Origen de la cortesía de poner "yo" al final

Tags: pronombres, historia, cortesía

Hemos investigado ya [en otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18982/12637) que poner "yo" al final de una enumeración es solo cuestión de cortesía [y no de lingüística](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yo):

> Por razones de cortesía, es costumbre colocarlo en último lugar cuando forma parte de una enumeración: *«Andrés, Quique y yo caminábamos entre las tumbas»* (GaRamis Días [P. Rico 1986]); no hay, sin embargo, justificación lingüística para censurar su anteposición: *«Te querrán tanto como yo y Leonardo D’Amaro te hemos querido»* (Alegre Locus [Esp. 1989]).

Sin embargo, vamos a intentar profundizar y a tirar de historia. ¿Cuál es el origen de esta cortesía? ¿Surgió en algún momento de la historia del español o viene de antes? ¿Tuvo en algún momento la RAE alguna opinión más estricta sobre el tema? (Quiero decir, que en algún momento obligara a poner "yo" al final.) ¿Cuál ha sido históricamente la opinión de la RAE sobre este tema? ¿Siempre ha sido la misma (la actual)?

Comment: Recuerdo una pregunta similar en English Language & Usage, ya que en inglés ocurre algo parecido. Supongo que es una simple traslación al lenguaje de la cortesía consistente en dejar pasar a otra persona por delante al cruzar una puerta, por ejemplo, pero no tengo ningún dato.

Answer (score 3):

Empiezo mencionando un refrán con el que a muchos nos han inculcado esta norma de cortesía: el burro por delante. Existen otras variantes:

- El burro/borrico por delante, para que no se espante.
- El burro/borrico delante, para que no se espante.
- El burro/borrico delante para que el asno no se espante.
- El burro/borrico delante y la carga atrás [1](http://hombrerefranero.blogspot.com.co/2011/09/el-burro-delante-para-que-no-se-espante.html).

Una explicación de dicho refrán y su conexión con la costumbre de usar "yo" al final se puede encontrar acá:

> Sin embargo, en la fraseología popular ha solido pesar más la concepción del borrico como un animal algo estúpido. Así, a los que anteponen el "yo" al resto de las personas gramaticales (*yo y tú, por ejemplo), se le dice aquello de "el burro por delante, que no se espante". Esta costumbre fue bastante común hasta el siglo XVIII, y Cervantes lo coloca antepuesto muchas veces. Sin embargo, la cortesía se fue imponiendo y en siglo XIX casi nadie se saltaba la norma. [2](http://ei-talondeaquiles.blogspot.com.co/2012/01/el-burro-por-delante.html)

En este otro sitio [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/biblioteca_fraseologica/n1_cantera/diversidad_09.htm#np168n) se menciona que además de lo relativo a la construcción de las frases, el refrán también inculca la cortesía de anteponer los demás a nosotros:

> Procede señalar que este dicho «El burro por delante para que no se espante» también se emplea para referirse a quien trata de pasar primero por delante de los demás.

Por último, un ejemplo de como Cervantes anteponía el "yo" [DON QVIXOTE DE LA MANCHA, p. 330](http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/cervante/dqsb1.htm), soportando lo que decía una referencia citada anteriormente:

> que ayer determinamos yo y quatro
>   zagales, los dos criados y los dos amigos mios,
>   de buscarle hasta tanto que le hallemos;